# Which is better for multi-use auth, MySQL, PostgreSQL, or LDAP?

Tags: linux, email, database, authentication, dovecot

I want to set up an Oracle Linux 6 server that gives users secure IMAP email (with dovecot), Jabber IM, FTP (with vsftpd), and calDav.  However, I want each user logon to be able to authenticate all services (e.g. Joe Smith signs up once for a username and password that he can use for email, ftp, and his calendar).  My question is, which database service will be best suited for that application?

Also, is there a way to link the database with the preexisting server shell logins (e.g. so I can read the root account's LogCheck emails on a different device)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly all services with authentication can work with LDAP while this isn't the case for SQL databases. So if you are not sure all your services can work with MySQL or PostgreSQL, chose LDAP.

Comment: Is there a way to link my current server login into LDAP?

Comment: Yes you can link your system users into LDAP. I don't know how much Oracle Linux differs from Redhat in this regard, but if it's similar you might be able to get enough information in https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Configuring_Authentication.html - otherwise search for Oracle Linux ldap auth

Comment: This should work as oracle linux is designed very similar to redhat.